# SwiftUI - .scrollPosition Modifier doesn't update binding Attribute

Tags: swiftui

I try to set a ScrollView to the top most element with a button. Therefor the new `.scrollPosition()` modifier should come in handy. I can't get it to work tho. In the following example the scrolling works when clicking on an item or the button at the bottom of the stack. But when scrolling the value is not updated. You can reproduce the behaviour by scrolling to the bottom, click the button "Scroll to top" and scroll back down. The second time, nothing happens because the value is still on 1. Am I doing something wrong or is my expectation of the modifier wrong? The documentation says so: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/scrollposition(id:anchor:)

```swift
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Test
//
//  Created by Sebastian Götte on 23.09.23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var scrollViewPosition: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack(spacing: 32) {
                ForEach(1..<21) { item in
                    Text("I am item no. \(item)")
                        .id(item)
                    
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .padding()
                        .background(.purple)
                        .cornerRadius(4)
                    
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                scrollViewPosition = item
                            }
                        }
                }
                
                Button("Scroll to top", action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        scrollViewPosition = 1
                    }
                })
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            .padding()
        }
        .scrollPosition(id: $scrollViewPosition, anchor: .top)
        
        .onChange(of: scrollViewPosition) { oldValue, newValue in
        print(newValue ?? "No value set")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using a `VStack` in the `ScrollView`. You need to use a `LazyVStack`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you change `VStack` to `LazyVStack`, your code works.

However, you might not be able to use `LazyVStack` for some reason. For example, in my app, I use a custom `Layout` inside my `ScrollView`.

If you cannot use `LazyVStack`, then (in my testing on iOS 17.0.1), using the `.id` modifier prevents SwiftUI from updating the `scrollPosition` binding. Instead of using `.id`, you need to rely on `ForEach`'s behavior of assigning an `id` to each of its subviews. This also means you need to use a version of `ForEach` that takes an `id:` parameter, or provide it with a collection of `Identifiable`-conforming values.

So, to make your example work, change your `ForEach` loop to this:

```swift
ForEach(1..<21, id: \.self) { item in
    Text("I am item no. \(item)")
        // .id modifier removed
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding()
        .background(.purple)
        .cornerRadius(4)
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                scrollViewPosition = item
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, that works. ScrollPosition seams also to be very picky with the id Type, i tried `UUID` as an id but that doesn't seam to work. `Strings` and `Ints` work fine tho

Comment: I had the same issue, and it turned out that even if you have ID a few levels down the hierarchy of the scrollable item, it still leads to the position update problem. Thank you for publishing this discovery.

Answer (score 0):

If someone arrived here from a Google search, check that you've added `.scrollTargetLayout()` to the relevant view inside the ScrollView definition.

See Apple's examples here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/scrollPosition(id:anchor:)

*(I know this is not an answer to the question, but it might be useful for people searching for `scrollPosition` troubleshooting)*