# SwiftUI ScrollView sliding weird

Tags: swiftui, uiscrollview, scrollview, horizontalscrollview, ios17

I added `.scrollTargetLayout()`, and `.scrollPosition(id: $scrollID)` to my `ScrollView`, and then used `ForEach` in `ScrollView` to generate 12 rectangles, and the `isTaped` variable will be converted when those rectangles are clicked. There is a `Spacer()` below that will appear when `isTaped` is true. But when I click on those rectangles, they change strangely(the id on rectangle isn't the correct), and the scroll id at the top can also be seen. The scroll id is not really changed. I want to ask why this is?

here is preview:
[The id change weird on Xcode preview](https://youtube.com/shorts/Hkfkk7_aNEc?feature=share),
[and it also](https://youtube.com/shorts/oc_vCcq5hm8?feature=share)

[This is the preview on Simulator](https://youtube.com/shorts/ZMiJpO_qelA?feature=share)

[It's preview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s963S.png)

here is my code below:

```swift
struct WeirdScrollView: View {
    @State private var isTaped: Bool = false
    @State private var scrollID: Int? = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text("scroll id: \(scrollID ?? 0)")
                
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    LazyHStack(alignment: .top) {
                        ForEach(0..<12, id: \.self) { i in
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                                .overlay {
                                    Text("id: \(i)")
                                        .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                                }
                                .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 3, spacing: 10.0)
                                .id(i)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    withAnimation {
                                        isTaped.toggle()
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    .scrollTargetLayout()
                }
                .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
                .scrollPosition(id: $scrollID)
                
                if isTaped {
                   Spacer(minLength: 300)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```

I was originally going to make a custom Date Picker(there is only one Date Picker on screen, and user can scroll it horizontal), but when I did the above things(change `isTaped`), something weird happened to it.
My project need scroll id to binding what rectangle is appear on screen, but when I remove the `.scrollPosition(id: $scrollID)`, and it run very well but not fit what I need

Comment: Difficult to reproduce your problem, but I think I saw it once.
Have you tried using `HStack` instead of `LazyHStack`?

Comment: If I use `HStack` to arrange those rectangles in a row, the scroll id remains unchanged when I scroll the ScrollView.

Comment: yes you are correct. Try the `HStack` and removing the `.id(i)`, seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some changes to your code, referring to rob mayoff's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77164152/swiftui-scrollposition-modifier-doesnt-update-binding-attribute). As he says I use `HStack` as opposed to `LazyHStack`.  As the picture below indicates, the scroll id text does change.  And the ID numbers over the rectangles remain the same.  One major changes is such that I have `ZStack` to encapsulate `RoundedRectangle` and the ID `Text` separately.

```
import SwiftUI

struct WeirdScrollView: View {
    @State private var isTapped: Bool = false
    @State private var scrollID: Int? = 0

    var body: some View {        
        VStack {
            Text("scroll id: \(scrollID ?? 0)")
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<12, id: \.self) { i in
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: isTapped ? 300 : .infinity)
                                .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 3, spacing: 10.0)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    withAnimation {
                                        isTapped.toggle()
                                        scrollID = i
                                    }
                                }
                            Text("id: \(i)")
                                .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            .scrollPosition(id: $scrollID)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are welcome.  I've realized that I had double `VStack`s.  So I've removed one.